# Ubuntu RVM Rails bash command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm

I just installed ubuntu, and after that I wanted to install RVM with ruby and rails 3.1.

Installations went fine but when I want to create a rails app it can't find the rails command.

I know I can create an alias, but when rvm changes its gemset, the alias-path would be wrong right?

This is my .bashrc file (/home/user/.bashrc):

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"


# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

So, I don't really know how to get this to work...

Help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: did you restart you commande line ?

Comment: I did just now, and now my rvm doesn't work anymore.. I created an alias for rvm, but it seems it lost it.. Do aliases go away after a restart of the command line?

Comment: @tim no they don't but I am guessing your alias is in the wrong place.  Can we see your .bashrc

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to

#### Add rvm to your .bashrc by adding a line like

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

> This will allow you to load rvm when you start a new bash session

#### create a new Gemset when you want a new rails.

The work flow should work like this

```
$ mkdir new_rails_app
$ cd new_rails_app
$ vim .rvmrc

# edit the .rvmrc to use the correct Gemset Something like 
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p180@new_rails_app --create

#save and exit vim

$ rvm rvmrc load
# you should see a prompt that your Gemset was loaded

$ gem install rails
$ rails new .
```

You now have a working rails directory for a new app using rvm.  There are other little tricks like auto loading your rvmrc's but I left that out just for the sake of the "easiest" route.

Comment: Still rvm command not found... changed the path to the rvm installation path after I tried the line you recommended, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: where are you putting in in your .bashrc can you put that file in your question

Comment: I've posted the file.. it's located in /home/user/.bashrc

Comment: throw your rvm line at the end of the file and then save and close out of terminal and re open it

Comment: still nothing.. i tried /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rvm-1.7.0, /usr/local/rvm, and the normal $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm. But the last folder doesn't even exist on my hdd.. but when i view my gem list, rvm 1.7.0 is there

Answer (score 4):

I meet the issue "**command not found: rails**" too, but I'm using **oh-my-zsh** for the shell prompt, and I fix the issue by copy the line

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

from file **~/.bashrc** to **~/.zshrc**, and it works well.
Hope it can give you some help.