# Configuring ruby on rails in gitlab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

I have setup and configured gitlab on my CentOS 6.5 server using this [guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md)

My gitlab is up and running, and what I wanted to do is to configure ruby on rails.

I can find rails in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/` but when trying to type in `rails -v` it gives me a bash: command not found.

I am trying to set up a rails server, anyone can guide me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are opening a new shell in order to take account a PATH modification referencing said commands.

See for instance "[rails-installer.sh runs fine but ruby, irb, rails command “not found” (UB12.04)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12872086/6309)". (for Ubuntu, but the idea remains the same for CentOS).

That supposes your `PATH` were correctly set in the first place.
If not, check your [`PATH` as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15729196/6309).